# Is "go to school" a phrasal verb?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

I remember when first I heard "I should go to school" the phrase was odd to me. We don't say "I should go to **the / a / my** ... school", *school* has no article, then I think it is the sign that the whole phrase "go to school" is a verb. right?

it is just an example and I think such phrases are much more.
Other examples are:

> Go home
>
> Get back to work

Answer (score 5):

No, *go to* is not a phrasal verb. The phrases *to university*, *to work*, etc... are adverbials of direction/location. The *to* belongs to the adverbial, not the verb. When you replace the adverbial with a pronoun, you'll notice that the *to* disappears with it, which would not be the case if we were dealing with phrasal verb:

> - He **went** *to China* last year.
> - He **went** *there* last year.

If you compare this to a phrasal verb, such as *go back*:

> - He **went back** to China last year.
> - He **went back** *there* last year.

You see that the particle or preposition remain when the adverbial (or in other cases the object) is converted to a pronoun. Since the *to* with *go to* does not remain, you can see that it is a part of the adverbial and *go* is the actual verb.

So, *go home* simply uses the same verb *go* as in *go to university*. The reason there is no *to* before *home*, is that it is already an adverb which just happens to have the same form as the noun:

> - I want to **go** *home*.
> - I want to **go** *to our home*.

However, the verb *get back to* **is** a phrasal verb. If you take it through the same check as I did on *go to* above, you'll notice that both the *back* and the *to* belong to the verb. The phrase is *get back to + something*, while with *go* you say that you *go + somewhere*.

> - I will **get back to** *the numbers* later in the meeting.
> - I will **get back to** *them* later in the meeting.

Comment: Excellent answer. What would you call the kinds of places which are unusual in that they don't take the definite article when used with "to"? They're not really proper nouns.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should post that as a question on ELU. I don't know what they're called, but I did find a post about *home* and similar words that don't take a preposition *to* when used as adverbials: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33652/why-is-to-not-used-before-home

Comment: Thank you, but still a part of question remains! as @JasonMelançon pointed, what you call such verbs? you mean *to school* is an adverb? can I say *I go to jungle* or *I go to upstairs*, I mean any name I like?!

Comment: You can say *go to **the jungle*** and *go **upstairs***. Upstairs is one of those adverbs like *home* that doesn't need a preposition. I don't know the name for this type of nouns if there even is one.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, "go to school," "go to work," "go to space" (i.e., outer space), "go to heaven," *et cetera* are all common. British English adds even more: "go to university" and "go to hospital," which I, as an American, find utterly jarring and tasteless. (Not really.)

I don't know if I'd call them "phrasal verbs," exactly. My understanding is that a phrasal verb is just a verb plus a preposition, which essentially anything can be put after. That would make "go to" a phrasal verb, but I don't think "go to" means anything more than just the separate meanings of "go" and "to" added together. I think they're just idioms, if somewhat basic and non-idiomatic idioms.

You should check out the [`phrasal-verbs`](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrasal-verbs) tag at our big sister site, [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you, I doubt they are just idioms because they break a grammatical rule, the noun in such phrases get no article. Then I would like to know their grammatical category and the related rules.

Comment: What grammatical rule are they breaking?

Comment: @Adam as the noun gets no article, and even with article it sounds odd, *I go to the school!*

Comment: And yet it's perfectly valid (AmEng) to use the article if you're talking about going to *the building*. eg. "Where did you go?"/"I went to the school to pick up some forms."

Comment: There is no rule requiring nouns to have articles in all situations..